# Why are some events don't execute when called?

Tags: python, pygame

Python 3.

Hello. I made a game which starts off with a main menu and when 'd' is pressed, it will cut to the game screen.

Before I made this main menu, when I would hold space bar, the shapes would rumble. Now when I press 'd' to start the game, the objects are displayed, but holding space bar doesn't do anything, and neither does pressing escape or closing the game. It seems like the keyboard events / game events are not being called anymore once the 'd' is pressed.
Code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time



BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)


# Edit the intensity of the shake (Must be one number apart)
# Ex: a = -100, b = 101. A is negative, B is positive
a = -4
b = 5
up = 10
intensity = (a, b)
startGame = True

# Image Loading

pygame.init()

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange(0, 700)
        self.y = random.randrange(0, 500)
        self.height = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.width = random.randrange(20, 70)
        self.x_change = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.y_change = random.randrange(-3, 3)
        self.color = random.sample(range(250), 4)

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_change
        self.y += self.y_change


class Ellipse(Rectangle):
    pass

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, self.color, [self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height])

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.x_change
        self.y += self.y_change

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():
    global event
    intro = True
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.fill(WHITE)
        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 45)
        smallText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 30)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Welcome to Crazy Rumble.", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((700 / 2), (100 / 2))
        TextSurff, TextRectt = text_objects("Press enter to start", smallText)
        TextRectt.center = ((700 / 2), (900 / 2))
        TextStart, TextRecttt = text_objects("Hold space to make the shapes shake!", smallText)
        TextRecttt.center = ((700 / 2), (225 / 2))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        screen.blit(TextSurff, TextRectt)
        screen.blit(TextStart, TextRecttt)
        pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            intro = False
            startGame = True

global intro
my_list = []
for number in range(600):
    my_object = Rectangle()
    my_list.append(my_object)
for number in range(600):
    my_object = Ellipse()
    my_list.append(my_object)
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    game_intro()
    game_intro = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        game_intro = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    # --- Main event loop
    while game_intro == False:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        for rect in my_list:
            rect.draw()
            rect.move()
        for rectElli in my_list:
            rectElli.draw()
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                rectElli.y_change = random.randrange(a, b)
                rectElli.x_change = random.randrange(a, b)
                rectElli.move()

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            print(up)
            print(intensity)
            up += 1
            if up % 10 == 0:
                a -= 1
                b -= -1
        else:
            a, b = -4, 5

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: `game_intro = True` this is replacing the function with a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just setting `keys` once with

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

You need to put that call inside the loop, so it gets updated after every event.